# Simple xpath question that drives me crazy

Tags: php, xml, xpath

below is the structure of a feed I managed to print the content using this xpath
`$xml->xpath('/rss/channel//item')`

the structure

```
<rss><channel><item><pubDate></pubDate><title></title><description></description><link></link><author></author></item></channel></rss>
```

However some of my files follow this structure

```
<feed xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" .....><entry><published></published><title></title><description></description><link></link><author></author></entry></feed>
```

and I guessed that this should be the xpath to get the content of entry

```
$xml->xpath('/feed//entry')
```

something that proved me wrong.

My question is what is the right xpath to use? Am i missing something else ?

**This is the code**

```
<?php

$feeds = array('http://feeds.feedburner.com/blogspot/wSuKU');


$entries = array();
foreach ($feeds as $feed) {
    $xml = simplexml_load_file($feed);
    $entries = array_merge($entries, $xml->xpath('/feed//entry'));
}

echo "<pre>"; print_r($entries); echo"</pre>";

?>
```

Comment: /feed//entry is ok (/feed/entry should work too). What exactly do you get? What doesn't work?

Comment: The `//` isn't necessary (it can be just `/`) but that query seems to work to me...

Comment: are there namespaces that you have left out of the example?

Comment: good guess, it's probably `<feed xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">`

Comment: What I get when `print_r` is Array ( ) . I have updated my question with the code I use

Comment: Your xpath looks correct and works in this [online tool](http://www.mizar.dk/XPath/Default.aspx). What error are you getting?

Comment: @unbeli, yes there is <feed xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" .....>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this:

```
$xml->registerXPathNamespace('f', 'http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom');
$xml->xpath('/f:feed/f:entry');
```

Comment: Worked! Thank you unbeli for your time! May I ask one more thing ? Imagine that I use two feeds in the array, one for each structure. Is there a way to combine the xPath so that it will work on both feeds ? Like if you don't find any results with /rss/channel//item use the code you posted. I hope I made myself understandable...

Comment: On the other hand is there a service that will produce me the same structure for any feed I will add ? ( I guess it's a work around )

Comment: well, try one xpath and if it returns nothing, try the other.

Comment: I believe one workaround is to pre-process the XML to remove all the references to namespaces before using XPath on it... of course, this may change the *meaning* of the XML in the process, so you probably want to be careful how you use it.

Comment: What I mean is that in the array I will add feeds that have both structures.

Comment: Generally I think that if you have two variants of a vocabulary to deal with (e.g in different namespaces) it's best to preprocess them into a common form first (as @Darien suggests), rather than trying to write queries that handle both formats. That's because you only need to write the preprocessing code once, and it will make all subsequent queries easier to write.

Comment: Yes I guess that would be a great solution. How can I preprocess the feeds and create a new xml feed? Please give me a starting point maybe with a tutorial. Thank you.

Comment: @Darien and @Michael Kay what if i have two times the code above and put all the results in a new array and print them ?

Comment: Consider checking the result of `$xml->getDocNamespaces()` and only do the above when needed.

Comment: @Punkis: Michael's advice is undoubtedly more sound, but for a quick fix, change `'/f:feed/f:entry'` to `'/f:feed/f:entry | /rss/channel//item'`. This XPath expression will give you a union of either type of feed item or entry.

Comment: +1 to unbeli for showing how to use namespaces as they were intended, instead of trying to nullify them.

Answer (score 2):

**If you want a single XPath expression that will work when applied to either an RSS or an ATOM feed, you could use either of the following XPath expressions:**

This one is the most precise, but also the most verbose:

```
(/rss/channel/item 
  | /*[local-name()='feed' and namespace-uri()='http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom']
      /*[local-name()='entry' and namespace-uri()='http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom'])
```

This one ignores the namespace of the ATOM elements and just matches on their `local-name()`:

```
(/rss/channel/item | /*[local-name()='feed']/*[local-name()='entry'])
```

This one is the most simple, but the least precise and the least efficient:

```
/*//*[local-name()='item' or local-name()='entry']
```