# Parsing XML, xpath wont work

Tags: php, simplexml, xml-parsing

Im currently working with parsing data from an api-response (xml) but i can't really parse the data. I've previously parsed XML repsonses with xpath, with great success, but in this case it doesnt work.

Here's my code:

```
    $personnr = $_POST['bcpn'];

    //Get string
    $getstring = 'CustomerLoginName=xxxx&UserLoginName=xxx&Password=xxx&Language=xxx&PersonNumber='.$personnr;
    //Target URL
    $url = "https://xxxxx.se/x/xxx.asmx/DataImport2Person?$getstring";
    //Creating Simple XMl Objects
    $xml = new SimpleXMLElement($url, null, true);
```

And here is the XML response:

```
<DataImport2Result xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://www.xxx.xxx/xxxx/xxx2">
<Number/>
<Blocks>
<Block>
<Code>PNrStatus</Code>
<Fields>
<Field>
<Code>PNrStatus</Code>
<Value>0</Value>
</Field>
<Field>
<Code>PNrStatusText</Code>
<Value>Registrerat personnummer</Value>
</Field>
</Fields>
</Block>
<Block>
<Code>Fbf</Code>
<Fields>
<Field>
<Code>FinnsIFbf</Code>
<Value>1</Value>
</Field>
<Field>
<Code>FinnsIFbfText</Code>
<Value>Ja</Value>
</Field>
<Field>
<Code>SkyddadMark</Code>
<Value>0</Value>
</Field>
<Field>
<Code>SkyddadMarkText</Code>
<Value>Nej</Value>
</Field>
<Field>
<Code>FbkMark</Code>
<Value>0</Value>
</Field>
<Field>
<Code>FbkMarkText</Code>
<Value/>
</Field>
<Field>
<Code>SparDatum</Code>
<Value>2000-01-01</Value>
</Field>
<Field>
<Code>PNr</Code>
<Value>19590707-1111</Value>
</Field>
<Field>
<Code>FNamn</Code>
<Value>Jan Olof</Value>
</Field>
<Field>
<Code>MNamn</Code>
<Value/>
</Field>
<Field>
<Code>ENamn</Code>
<Value>Håkansson</Value>
</Field>
<Field>
<Code>Coadress</Code>
<Value/>
</Field>
<Field>
<Code>Gatuadress</Code>
<Value>Götgatan</Value>
</Field>
<Field>
<Code>Postnr</Code>
<Value>12639</Value>
</Field>
<Field>
<Code>Postort</Code>
<Value>HÄGERSTEN</Value>
</Field>
<Field>
<Code>TNamn</Code>
<Value>Jan</Value>
</Field>
</Fields>
</Block>
<Block>
<Code>TaxAr1</Code>
<Fields>
<Field>
<Code>TaxAr</Code>
<Value>2010</Value>
</Field>
<Field>
<Code>InkTj</Code>
<Value>211620</Value>
</Field>
<Field>
<Code>InkNarvAkt</Code>
<Value>0</Value>
</Field>
<Field>
<Code>InkNarvPass</Code>
<Value>0</Value>
</Field>
<Field>
<Code>UskNarvAkt</Code>
<Value>0</Value>
</Field>
<Field>
<Code>UskNarvPass</Code>
<Value>0</Value>
</Field>
<Field>
<Code>AllmAvdr</Code>
<Value>5500</Value>
</Field>
<Field>
<Code>TaxForvInk</Code>
<Value>206100</Value>
</Field>
<Field>
<Code>InkKap</Code>
<Value>0</Value>
</Field>
<Field>
<Code>UndKap</Code>
<Value>21908</Value>
</Field>
<Field>
<Code>SamInk</Code>
<Value>184192</Value>
</Field>
<Field>
<Code>SlutSkatt</Code>
<Value>41130</Value>
</Field>
<Field>
<Code>EjFast</Code>
<Value>0</Value>
</Field>
<Field>
<Code>EjFastText</Code>
<Value>Nej</Value>
</Field>
<Field>
<Code>NollTax</Code>
<Value>0</Value>
</Field>
<Field>
<Code>NollTaxText</Code>
<Value>Nej</Value>
</Field>
</Fields>
</Block>
</Blocks>
</DataImport2Result>
```

As you can see there's alot of "block" which is where the data is located, the ideal Solution for me would be an array where it says `<code> => <value>`.

I would appreciate any help and suggestions.

All the best,
Marten

Comment: And what's the problem? Why is it that you *can't really parse the data*? What *doesnt work*? SimpleXML can use XPath and is iterateable. Sounds like gimme-teh-codez right now.

Comment: The problem is that xpath wont work, eventhough I am using the "wildcard" which is //

Comment: `foreach(simplexml_load_file($apiUrl)->Blocks->Block as $block) {`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Simple XPath question that drives me crazy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6299201/simple-xpath-question-that-drives-me-crazy) and basically any of these http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=registerXPathNamespace

Answer (score 1):

You might be missing the namespace. All your elements are in the `http://www.xxx.xxx/xxxx/xxx2` namespace, so you have to first issue [this command](http://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.registerxpathnamespace.php):

```
$xml->registerXPathNamespace('x', 'http://www.xxx.xxx/xxxx/xxx2');
```

Then you can address your elements with:

```
//x:Code
```

Comment: If that is the issue, the question is a duplicate

Comment: Yes, but if you haven’t heard the phrase “XML Namespace” before, it’s hard to search for it.

Comment: It's not hard to search for http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=xpath+not+working+php. It's only more effort to single out the first five results that dont answer the question.